# How do you modify the location of a service reference at runtime?

Tags: .net, web-services, url

I have a client VB .NET 3.5 WPF app which is basically a test harness - it calls a webservice (a classic .NET 2.0 webservice, NOT a WCF app) that's in the same solution. to check some of the service methods runs correctly.

I've added the service to the the client project in VS as a Service Reference, and set the solution for both projects to be startup projects. That works fine when I'm debugging and running the whole thing locally. But the problem is, I need the user to be able to type in a URL at runtime, and have the test harness check out the service at the specified URL, not the one at the location that VS is running. This is so the test harness can check out already deployed copies of the web service. The problem is there doesn't seem to be any way in the service reference to make the URL dynamic and settable from the VB code. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can dynamic point client to service. The service reference is a proxy of your service.

I belive that you can use the other constructor of service reference(service proxy) that take a Url as parameter.

e.g. YourServiceProxy("Target url")

If you user change/edit the service url, i think you can initail other service proxy instance that take url which user specify.

Comment: Cheers, that wasn't quite right, but was close enough to lead me to the correc answer.  The 1-parameter constructor expects to use the parameter not as a URL but to look up the endpoint name in the app.config (which was will have been put there by VS on adding the webreference. But there's a two-parameter constructor which appears to let you override the URL for the given endpoint name.  ServiceProcy("endpoint name", "actual url")

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change the URL of a web service at run-time: 

In the config.sys (or app.config) file, look for a xml tag <endpoint . . .>. 

Copy the entire endpoint tag and its contents, and paste the copy just below the original in the same file.

Change the name attribute of the new copy to a new name (let's say the new name is "NewName" for this example); change the address attribute to the new URL.

In the code, create the service reference as before, but in the "new" statement, use one parameter for the class constructor, the new name:

ServiceReference1.MyClient cl = new ServiceReference1.MyClient("NewName");

Then call the ServiceReferences methods just as before:

String sRes = cl.MyMethod(myParm);

This works in Visual Basic as well, just use VB syntax in the code.