# What is the best way to move FedEx .net webservices from developer environment to production?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008, asmx, fedex

FedEx doesn't provide UDDI services but need to be downloaded as a WSDL file.  Once the developement is complete, the development WSDL need to be replaced with production WSDL.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 and just replacing the WSDL doesn't automatically work in production, but need to be reimported and rebuild the project.  This creates two different binary signatures for both devlopment and production environments.  I need to accomplish this through some configuration files so my binaries will be same for my development and production environments.  Any ideas???  Thanks!

The only change in WSDL filess is location value.

```
 <port name="RateServicePort" binding="ns:RateServiceSoapBinding">
      <s1:address location="https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services" />
    </port>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't only need to change the URL of the webservice, not the entire WSDL?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231582/how-do-you-modify-the-location-of-a-service-reference-at-runtime ?

Comment: We put the url for the web service in the config files. When we go to production, we have a copy of the config files with the production url.

Comment: That doesn't work inthis scenario as these services are not UDDI.  Visual Studio 2008 puts this in generated reference.cs and settings.cs files.

Comment: The WSDL is not used at runtime. The answer from "Al G" below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We normally override the URL, similar to how Dave Zych said, along these lines:

```
prod = new Service.Service();
// ... read configuration into cfg ...
prod.Url = cfg.ServiceURL;
```

The URL changes depending on the environment via the configuration. The WSDL is consistent, as are the underlying classes.

Comment: When you say read the configuration into cfg, is it web.config/app.config file?

Comment: That was me generalizing a bit. What I mean is: load the URL from your configuration and set it into the URL member. Where you store it is up to you.